# Get Richtextbox1.Text value into a webbrowser search bar?

Tags: vb.net, browser, richtextbox, getelementbyid

I'm playing around in VB.NET currently and I'm trying to make it so that the value from my Richtextbox1 goes into my webbrowsers search bar (It's navigating to http://google.com currently..)!

The 'class' of the search bar is "gbqfif".. I was trying things like:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfif")
```

Then basically I would invoke a click on the button itself, just trying to get the richtextbox value working first!

If anyone could help, I'd love it! (I searched SOF first before posting)

EDIT: Getting this error alot:

> Error 1   'GetElementByClass' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the complete opposite. Your code assigns a text from the webbrowser to the RichTextBox. Change the code to

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfif").InnerText = RichTextBox1.Text
```